# Multiple Layout Managers in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, layout

Is there way to use more than 1 layout manager in Java. Right now I'm using a gridLayout to implement a chess board but beneath it I would like to put some other stuff but not in a gridLayout. Maybe a FlowLayout or some other layout. How would I go about doing this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Yes, all you need is to plan your over all UI Layout (i.e; Window, master panel etc)

For example, you need to put something under your chessboard, I would normally go with a BorderLayout at the basic level.

So assume I have a JPanel called masterPanel, that holds all the components for my chess app.
So, code would look like:

```
JPanel masterPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel chessBoardPanel = createChessboardPanel(); //assuming this method will return a
//JPanel with chess board using GridLayout
JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel(); //this is the panel that would contain info elements, that //may go below my chess board.
//Now add everything to master panel.
masterPanel.add(chessBoardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
masterPanel.add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
//add masterPanel to your window (if required)
this.getContentPane().add(masterPanel);
```

Answer (score 8):

> Is there way to use more than 1 layout
>   manager in Java.

Absolutely. In fact, using multiple layout managers is the norm.

> How would I go about doing this?

Any `Container` subclass can have a `LayoutManager` and contain child elements. And each of these child elements can itself be a `Container` with children. The most commonly used container below the top-level frames is `JPanel`.

For your example, you should probably use a `BorderLayout` for the frame, put a `JPanel` with the grid in its CENTER position (because that's the one that gets all available remaining space when the other positions have been given their preferred sizes) and another `JPanel` with the "other stuff" in the SOUTH position.

More details can be found in the [Swing tutorial on layout managers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).